# Making apps communicate with each other (?)

Tags: communication, iphone, app, internet

A friend of me and I would like to easily know if stuff like chores were done, and we're both in two different locations.

So, would it be very hard (would I need a lot of experience?) and take a lot of time to make an app that both me and my friend can have on our iPhones that communicates with each other over for example the internet (wi-fi, 3G, 4G/LTE), so I can press a checkbox next to "I did this and that" and then he can check his app and see that I checked that checkbox?

Would this be very advanced to make and/or be extremely time consuming? I studied basic HTML and Java programming for two years in school, but that's it.

Comment: Normally you wouldnt want your apps to communicate directly with each other, though I'm sure it's possible to do with some hacking (like sending SMS'es to each other - but then again, I don't know what the iPhone API allows you to do). You'd be better off building a server which both your phones communicates to and that stands in the middle as a mediator of messages passed between the application instances.

Answer (score 2):

> Would this be very advanced to make and/or be extremely time consuming? I studied basic HTML and Java programming for two years in school, but that's it.

It's not very advanced, but that doesn't mean that it'd be easy to do when you've never built an iOS application before. Your best bet would be to use a tool that already exists. Your second best option is to build something using the tools and knowledge that you already have.

If you google "online shared checklist" you'll find a number of tools that seem to do exactly what you want: create lists of tasks that you can mark as done, and share your lists with other people. Tools like [Trello](http://trello.com), [TickTock](https://ticktick.com), and [Forgett](https://www.forgett.com) are just a few of the many, many options. Even a shared document in Google Docs could work just fine. Many of these services have free or very inexpensive apps that you can use on your phones for a better user experience.

If you really want to build your own task tracking tool, you should use the technology that you already know. Native iOS apps are great, but the requirements that you've stated are very simple and would be easy to fulfill with a basic web page. So start there: build a page that lets you add and remove items from a list and mark them as done, and make the page maintain its state. Just that much would probably meet the need you've expressed -- you don't even need separate user accounts for you and your friend. If you want to improve it after that, you could add multiple user accounts, customize it to work really well with mobile phones, and maybe allow multiple sets of items. But be sure to look at what's out there first, because I think you'll probably end up creating something that's similar to an existing tool.